# Scrolling another page on xfce4 hides active window

Tags: linux, xfce

I have used unity, gnome, lxde before but in xfce4, when Chrome is visible and my active window is a terminal, I scroll in Chrome with mouse however the terminal disappears and Chrome becomes active window. What causes this and how can I fix this? The other ones are used were keeping the Terminal active but scrolling the Chrome independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable that functionality, you need to go to **Settings » Window Manager Tweaks** once there go to the ** Accessibility** tab and uncheck the option **Raise windows when any mouse button is pressed**.

Like this

[image: I like turtles]